# Cordova Build causing xcodeBuild to quit unexpectedly

Tags: xcode, cordova, xcodebuild

I've got a basic react app running in Cordova, when I run a

```
cordova build ios
```

Things seem to work OK but then after a short delay I get the following:

[image]

If I run a

```
cordova run ios
```

I get the following

> No target specified for emulator. Deploying to iPhone-X, 12.1
>   simulator
>   /Users/Liam/code/*ProjectName*/app-src/platforms/ios/build/emulator/*ProjectName*/Info.plist
>   file not found.

I've done the usual, clean, remove platform, re-add platform but same issues. Any ideas what causes this or how to debug further?

I can run the Cordova App from XCode

Comment: any resolution found? stuck at the same issue atm but with newer versions :(

Comment: No, we ended up switching to React Native

Comment: thx. I was able to resolve the issue by running the simulated app from inside xcode... not great but a workaround